# Fork and waiting for the childs outside the pid check

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, wait

I want to make two parallel working forks and in the end wait for them to finish.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot fork!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(pid == 0) {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                //first child
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
            case 1: 
                //second child
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
    else {
        //parent
    }
}
```

The problem is that the main program terminates before the child ones. If I add wait(0) to the else parent part it waits to every process so they don't work at the same time but one by one.
I assumed that I can simply put the wait() or waitpid() after the loop but that's not working either. I thought that after the fork the parent continues normally so why doesn't it wait when the wait() is outside the loop and if-else structure?

Sorry for bothering and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `wait(NULL)` inside the else parent part, the parent-process will indeed wait for the first child-process to return before it creates the second.

If you add `wait(NULL)` after the loop, the parent process will wait **only once**, for the first child-process that will return.

If you want all children-processes to run at the same time, you need a second loop, where the parent-process will use `wait()` as many times as needed to collect the exit status of **every** child-process.

In your case, there are 2 children-processes, thus 2 `wait()` system calls are enough. The loop to add would be like this (I also added a `printf` so that you can observe it on your `stdout`):

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("My child No %d died.\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't realize that it waits for each one exit status. I have problems to imagine how this works. Thank you very much :-)